# Can someone tell me how to implement this Javascript? HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this awesome link with a scroll-to-top button that I'd like to add to my web page. Can someone tell me how to implement the javascript part? I tried inserting it at the bottom of my html page in script tags, but it doesn't seem to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/J3zyq/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('#goTop').stop().animate({
                top: '20px'    
                }, 500);
        }
        else{
            $('#goTop').stop().animate({
               top: '-100px'    
            }, 500);
        }
    });
    $('#goTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: 0
        }, 500, function() {
           $('#goTop').stop().animate({
               top: '-100px'    
           }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

Otherwise I know how to style and configure the HTML and CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you load jQuery as well?

Comment: It works in the fiddle. You probably aren't loading jQuery on your page.

Comment: This is jQuery. A point blank easy tell is the first line of code. `$(document).ready(function() {` Do you also have a jQuery library loaded?

Comment: Fiddle works fine, just recreate what you have in the Fiddle, make sure you're including jQuery correctly.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks everyone. I'm working "offline" while designing this website, I guess it's time to load it to the FTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line of code in your `<head>` (above the rest of your JavaScript)

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Or if the code is not compatible with 2.1.3, you can use this one instead:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If it works after that, then you just didn't have jQuery loaded. It will load faster if you save jQuery locally but this is fine for testing purposes.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try this once I have access to the FTP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Download a js file called Jquery and put this line inside the head tag

```
<script src="MYLOCATION/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then put in your JS code in the head tag, enclosed in a script tag e.g.

```
<script src="MYLOCATION/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {....
</script>
```